# For the same URL, the request library works normally, but the axios library returns an error

Tags: node.js, request, axios, web-crawler

I requested the same URL to axios, request.

URL : https://i1.coinone.co.kr/api/talk/latest_notice

But request works fine and axios returns 404 error. What's the difference?

```
var request = require('request');
request("https://i1.coinone.co.kr/api/talk/latest_notice", function (error, response, body) {
  if(error){
    console.log("request Error");
  }else{
    console.log("request Success", body);
  }
});

var axios = require('axios').default;
axios.get("https://i1.coinone.co.kr/api/talk/latest_notice").then(function (body) {
   console.log("axios Success", body.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
   console.log("axios Error", error.message);
})
```

result : request (success), axios (failed)

```
axios Error Request failed with status code 404
request Success {"id":1194,"notice_type":"공지","title":"리니어 파이낸스(LINA), 크립토뱅크(CBANK) 원화마켓 상장 안내 / Linear(LINA), Crypto Bank(CBANK) KRW Market Listing"}
```

Comment: Seems to be some issue with axios not setting the received cookie/headers after the 301-redirect.

Comment: How to solve this problem?